# Generate HTML code from a selectbox value which change randomly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, innerhtml

I have a problem with a selectbox. I have implemented a selectbox in which you can choose (click on an option) a brand and get some information about it (prices). To do it I use ajax and innerhtml -> it works !

Today, what I want to do is to change randomly the value of the selectbox and generate information using my ajax call (innerhtml). I succeed changing every 2 seconds the value of the selectbox but the innerhtml doesn't work. It works only when I click and change manually...

Can you help me to generate the innerhtml please ?

Here is my php code which I use in order to create the selectbox :

```
<div id="listeMarques" onclick="stopChangingSelectedOption();">


        <?php

            global $wpdb;
            $query=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_marques ORDER BY brand_name");

            $dropdown = "<select name='brands' id='selectBrand'>";
            $dropdown .= "<option value='none'> Choisissez une marque </option>";

            foreach ($query as $page){

                $brand=htmlspecialchars($page->brand_name,ENT_COMPAT);
                $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='".$page->brand_id."'>".$brand."</option>";
            }
            $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

            echo $dropdown;

        ?>



    </div>
```

And my javascript code below dealing with ajax call and setInterval to change randomly selectbox value :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    /* FONCTION ROULETTE ALEATOIRE*/
    var changeOption;

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        changeOption=setInterval(changeSelectedOption,2000);

    });


    function stopChangingSelectedOption(){
        clearInterval(changeOption);
    }

    function changeSelectedOption(){
        //alert("c'est buen");
        var option = jQuery('#selectBrand option')
        var index=Math.floor(Math.random()*option.length)+1;

        jQuery("select option:nth-child("+index+")").prop("selected",true);
    }


    /* FONCTION GENERATEUR DU TABLEAU DE PRIX EN FONCTION DE LA MARQUE*/
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery('#listeMarques').change(function(){

                var $idBrand = jQuery('#selectBrand').val();
                //alert("value : " + $idBrand);

                    jQuery.ajax({

                    type:"POST",
                    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",

                    /*data: {

                        action: "vendorprcicing",

                        Brand_id : $idBrand

                    },*/
                    data: "action=vendorpricing&Brand_id="+$idBrand,

                    success:function(data){
                    jQuery("#estimationPrix").html(data);
                    },

                    error: function(errorThrown){
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }  
                        });



                    return false;


            });
        });</script>
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have bound most of the functionality to the `change` event of the `select` element. This event won’t be triggered however if you’re just setting the `selected` property on one of the `option` elements.

An easy way out would be to simply trigger the `change` event manually after setting the option:

```
function changeSelectedOption(){
    var option = jQuery('#selectBrand option')
    var index=Math.floor(Math.random()*option.length)+1;

    jQuery("select option:nth-child("+index+")").prop("selected",true);

    jQuery('#listeMarques').trigger('change'); // <----- HERE
}
```

Here’s a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yLKbM/

It might make sense to split the functionality a bit further and simply call a function which then reads the state of the select and which could be used in both cases, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your response, I noticed that I had to add .trigger('change') after prop("selected",true). Now it works perfectly ;)

Thanks again !

Comment: No problem, glad it works. Please consider leaving a comment in the future rather than opening a new answer for cases like this. Good luck!